# Search in dictionary with keywords, python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some function like this one, input is one list with some keywords (strings) and returns the key that better fit with all keywords store in the dictionary:

```
def find_my_keyword(str1):
   dict_colour = {
       "y": {'has':["yellow", "white", "green"], 'hasnt':[]},
       "z": {'has':["yellow", "white"], 'hasnt': ["green"]},
       "z2": {'has':["yellow", "white", "1."], 'hasnt': ["green"]} }

     for colour, keywords in dict_colour.items():
        if all(kw in str1 for kw in keywords['has']) and not any(kw in str1 for kw in keywords['hasnt']):
              return colour


find_my_keyword(str1)
```

I tried with this strings:

```
str1 = ("white, "yellow", "1.2")
str2 = ("white, "yellow", "1.")
str3 = ("white, "yellow", "1.24")
```

The function only return colour with str2, that has exactly the same items, is there is any way to make that the function would return a colour when the substring (1.) is in the string (1.2 or 1.24) as well?

I tried also with this one, but not good results:

```
for colour, keywords in dict_colour.items():
    if all(kw in keywords['has'] for kw in str1 ) and not any(kw in keywords['hasnt'] for kw in str1):
          return colour
```

Comment: What does 'it takes one string and returns the key that better fit in the search' mean? I don't understand your question.

Comment: I edited, I hope that now the question is more understandable

Comment: *"not good results"* - what does that mean?! Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you're running and a concise description of the problem with it. Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to test if all of the strings in str1 appear as substrings in strings in `keywords['has']`.

In that case, you could use:

```
for colour, keywords in dict_colour.items():
    if all(any(keystring in kw for keystring in keywords['has']) for kw in str1 ) and not any(kw in keywords['hasnt'] for kw in str1):
        return colour
```

Answer (score 0):

This will consider `1.2` and `1.` etc.. to be the same

```
def find_my_keyword(str1):
    dict_colour = {
        "y": {'has': ["yellow", "white", "green"], 'hasnt': []},
        "z": {'has': ["yellow", "white"], 'hasnt': ["green"]},
        "z2": {'has': ["yellow", "white", "1."], 'hasnt': ["green"]}}
    for colour, keywords in dict_colour.items():
        k_w = keywords["has"]
        if all(x in k_w or x.split(".")[0] + "." in k_w for x in str1):
            return colour
    return False
```

You only need to check if all the words in `str1` are in `keywords["has"]` if they all are then there cannot be any in `keywords["hasnt"]`

`x.split(".")[0] + "."` changes `1.24` to `1.` so it returns `True` when checked against `1.`